# How to make a count down timer on button when triggered

Tags: python, tkinter

So Im trying to create a count down timer in the form of mm:ss and start counting down in an interval of 1 second when the button is being pressed. Im trying to make the timer show on the button too when counting down. This is what I have so far and I'm not sure what to do.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
monsterTimer = '00:02'
def converter(sec):
    m, s = map(int, sec.split(":"))
    sec = m * 60 + s
    sec -= 1
    m, s = divmod(sec, 60)
    sec = (f'{m:02d}:{s:02d}')
    if sec != '00:00':
        sec = 'end'
    root.after(1000, converter)
    return sec

def update_btn_text():
    btn_text.set(converter(monsterTimer))

btn_text = tk.StringVar()
btn_text.set(monsterTimer)
btn = tk.Button(root, textvariable=btn_text, command=lambda: update_btn_text())
btn.place(x=10, y=10)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please include the error you are getting when you run this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution was close, and using `after` instead of threads is the right way to go.

The first problem is that when you use `root.after`, you are calling `converter` but you aren't passing in an argument. You need to change the line to look like the following, which will call `converter(sec)` every second.

```
root.after(1000, converter, sec)
```

Another problem you have is that you are setting `set` to `'end'` if it is *not* 00:00. You need to set it only if it *is* 00:00:

```
if sec == '00:00':
    sec = 'end'
```

Third, you need to update the button text inside of `converter`, sometime before calling `after`:

```
...
btn_text.set(sec)
root.after(1000, converter, sec)
```

Finally, you don't need `update_btn` at all. It can be removed, and you can call `converter` from your button command.

```
btn = tk.Button(root, textvariable=btn_text, command=lambda: converter(monsterTimer))
```

---

Putting it all together, it looks like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
monsterTimer = '00:10'
def converter(sec):
    m, s = map(int, sec.split(":"))
    sec = m * 60 + s
    sec -= 1
    m, s = divmod(sec, 60)
    sec = (f'{m:02d}:{s:02d}')
    if sec == '00:00':
        sec = 'end'
    btn_text.set(sec)
    if sec != "end":
        root.after(1000, converter, sec)

btn_text = tk.StringVar()
btn_text.set(monsterTimer)
btn = tk.Button(root, textvariable=btn_text, command=lambda: converter(monsterTimer))
btn.place(x=10, y=10)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
import threading

root = tk.Tk()
monsterTimer = '00:00'
run_tm = 5


def update_btn_text(sec):
    while sec:
        m, s = divmod(sec, 60)
        m, s = str(m).zfill(2), str(s).zfill(2)
        tm = f'{m}:{s}'
        btn_text.set(tm)
        time.sleep(1)
        sec -= 1
    btn_text.set("00:00")


def startThread(t):
    th1 = threading.Thread(target=update_btn_text, args=(t, ))
    th1.start()


btn_text = tk.StringVar()
btn_text.set(monsterTimer)
btn = tk.Button(root, textvariable=btn_text, command=lambda: startThread(run_tm))
btn.place(x=50, y=50)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It creates another thread which we used to call `update_btn_text` function. If we do it with main thread, IDK why but tkinter button freezes.